# Image is not displayed for slider class in div, but it is in elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

The images in list with `.slider` class are not being displayed in browser window using MaterializeCSS, but it can be seen in elements. Do sequence of .css and .js loading in head matter?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="416.jpg">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="417.jpg">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may be because you are  not setting any width and height of the img tag. Also there is multiple version of jquery. Please refer to this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/b4xs7ors/)

Comment: Remove opacity: 0 for .slider .slides li

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are including two versions of jQuery, remove the `<script>` tag for `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`.

The images are not being displayed because you are not initializing the `slider`. Add the following jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.slider').slider();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `opacity: 0` for `.slider .slides li`